# stackoverflow error in 2d fipy PDE solver in python

Tags: python, stack-overflow, ode, pde, fipy

I am trying to solve a system of three coupled PDEs and two ODEs (coupled) in 2D. The problem tries to solve for a case of a particle moving in a medium. The medium is given by the fields- velocity components vx, vy, and density m and there is one particle moving in this medium with position Rx, Ry.

It runs fine for a while but then throws up errors:
"Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow.
Current thread 0x00007fe155915700 (most recent call first):"

Here is the code:

```
"""

"""

from fipy import (CellVariable, PeriodicGrid2D, Viewer, TransientTerm, DiffusionTerm,
                  UniformNoiseVariable, LinearLUSolver, numerix,
                  ImplicitSourceTerm, ExponentialConvectionTerm, VanLeerConvectionTerm,
                  PowerLawConvectionTerm, Variable)

import sys
import inspect

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage

from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.signal import correlate
from scipy.stats import kurtosis
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

numerix.random.seed(2)

def run_simulation(f0, Total_time):

    # Define mesh size and number of points
    nx = 50
    ny = nx
    L = 50
    dx = L / nx
    dy = dx
    
    mesh = PeriodicGrid2D(dx, dy, nx, ny)
    
    # Variables to use
    vx = CellVariable(name='vx', mesh=mesh, hasOld=1)
    vy = CellVariable(name='vy', mesh=mesh, hasOld=1)
    m = CellVariable(name='m', mesh=mesh, hasOld=1)
    
    # Initial condition
    m.setValue(UniformNoiseVariable(mesh=mesh, minimum=0.6215, maximum=0.6225))
    vx.setValue(UniformNoiseVariable(mesh=mesh, minimum=0, maximum=0.00001))
    vy.setValue(UniformNoiseVariable(mesh=mesh, minimum=0, maximum=0.00001))

    #particle position
    x0=10.0
    y0=25.0
    # create grids for grad function
    xgrid=np.unique(mesh.x.value)+dx/2
    ygrid=np.unique(mesh.y.value)+dy/2

    # parameters ------------------------------
    B=4.0
    Gamma=1.0
    gamma=1.0
    Dm=0.005
    C=100.0
    ## save the initial positions in Rx,Ry
    Rx=Variable(value=x0)
    Ry=Variable(value=y0)
    theta=Variable(value=0.0)               # n-hat = cos(theta) x-hat + sin(theta) y-hat
    sigma = 1
    dt = 0.05
    #-----------------------------------------

    x_hat = [1.0, 0.0]
    y_hat = [0.0, 1.0]

    #------------- dirac delta function -------------- 
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58041222/dirac-delta-source-term-in-fipy

    def delta_func(x, y, epsilon):
        return ((x < epsilon) & (x > -epsilon) & (y < epsilon) & (y > -epsilon)) * \
        (1 + numerix.cos(numerix.pi * x / epsilon) * numerix.cos(numerix.pi * y / epsilon)) / 2 / epsilon



    ############## equations #############
    # renormalized parameters by Gamma
    
    # fields : velocity vector, density scalar
    #       Gamma * v = -B rho(grad(rho)) + f* n-cap* delta(r-R),     B>0, f>0, Gamma>0
    #       dot(rho) + del.(v rho) = 0
    # particle
    #       dot(R) = (f/gamma)*(n-cap) - (C/gamma) * rho(grad(rho))      C>0

    # Gamma=gamma=1,  B' = B/Gamma, C'=C/gamma, f'=f/Gamma

    ######################################

    eq_m = (TransientTerm(var=m) + ExponentialConvectionTerm(coeff=x_hat * vx + y_hat * vy, var=m) ==  DiffusionTerm(coeff=Dm, var=m) )

    eq_vx = (ImplicitSourceTerm(coeff=1., var=vx) == -(B/Gamma)*m.grad.dot(x_hat)*(m) + (f0/Gamma)*numerix.cos(theta)* delta_func(mesh.x-Rx,mesh.y-Ry,sigma) )

    eq_vy = (ImplicitSourceTerm(coeff=1., var=vy) == -(B/Gamma)*m.grad.dot(y_hat)*(m) + (f0/Gamma)*numerix.sin(theta)* delta_func(mesh.x-Rx,mesh.y-Ry,sigma) )

    eq = eq_m & eq_vx & eq_vy

    viewer = Viewer(vars=(m))
    
    elapsed = 0.0
    
    ms = []
    vxs = []
    vys = []
    xs = []
    ys = []
    
    while elapsed < Total_time:
        # Old values are used for sweeping when solving nonlinear values
        vx.updateOld()
        vy.updateOld()
        m.updateOld()

        print(elapsed, Rx, Ry)      

        mgrid=np.reshape(m.value,(nx,ny))
        # gradient cal, dydx[0][x,y], dydx[1][x,y] -> x derivative, y derivative at x,y
        dydx=np.gradient(mgrid,dx,dy,edge_order=2)
        # impose periodic boundary on gradient
        dydx[0][nx-1,:]=(mgrid[0,:]-mgrid[nx-2,:])/(2.0*dx)
        dydx[0][0,:]=(mgrid[1,:]-mgrid[nx-1,:])/(2.0*dx)
        dydx[1][:,ny-1]=(mgrid[:,0]-mgrid[:,ny-2])/(2.0*dy)
        dydx[1][:,0]=(mgrid[:,1]-mgrid[:,ny-1])/(2.0*dy)
        

        # solve ode
        idx = np.argmin(np.abs(xgrid - Rx))
        idy = np.argmin(np.abs(ygrid - Ry))

        x0=x0+ ((f0/gamma)*np.cos(theta) - C*mgrid[idx,idy]*dydx[0][idx,idy])*dt
        y0=y0+ ((f0/gamma)*np.sin(theta) - C*mgrid[idx,idy]*dydx[1][idx,idy])*dt

        if(x0>L):
          x0=x0-L
        if(x0<0):
          x0=x0+L

        if(y0>L):
          y0=y0-L
        if(y0<0):
          y0=y0+L

           
        Rx.setValue(x0) # element-wise assignment did not work 
        Ry.setValue(y0)

        elapsed += dt
        
        res = 1e5
        old_res = res * 2
        step = 0
        while res > 1e-5 and step < 5 and old_res / res > 1.01:            
            old_res = res
            res = eq.sweep(dt=dt)
            step += 1


        # The variable values are just numpy arrays so easy to use!
        # save velocity & density
        vxs.append(vx.value.copy())
        vys.append(vy.value.copy())
        ms.append(m.value.copy())


        viewer.plot()
    # save x and y positions
    xs.append(mesh.x.value.copy())
    ys.append(mesh.y.value.copy())
        
    return ms, vxs, vys, xs, ys

if __name__ == '__main__':

    path = 'result/'

    Total_time= 50  #40
    
    f0 = 2
    ms, vxs, vys, xs, ys = run_simulation(f0,Total_time)

    name = 'f0_{:.4f}'.format(f0)
        
    y = np.array([ms, vxs, vys])
    xx = np.reshape(xs,(50,50))
    yy = np.reshape(ys,(50,50))
    vx = np.reshape(vxs[800][:],(50,50))
    vy = np.reshape(vys[800][:],(50,50))
    print(np.shape(xx), np.shape(xs), np.shape(vx))
    #np.save(path + name, y)

    plt.imshow(np.reshape(ms[800][:],(50,50)), aspect='auto', interpolation='bicubic', cmap='jet', extent=[0, 50, 50, 0])
    plt.colorbar(label='density m')
    plt.xlabel(r'$x $')
    plt.ylabel(r'$y $')
    plt.gcf().savefig(path + 'rho_'+name+'.png', format='png', bbox_inches='tight')    
    plt.clf()

#---------------------------------------------
    plt.imshow(np.reshape(vxs[800][:],(50,50)), aspect='auto', interpolation='bicubic', cmap='jet', extent=[0, 50, 50, 0])
    plt.colorbar(label='velocity vx')
    plt.xlabel(r'$x $')
    plt.ylabel(r'$y $')
    plt.gcf().savefig(path + 'vel_'+name+'.png', format='png', bbox_inches='tight')    
    plt.clf()

#---------------------------------------------
    plt.quiver(xx,yy,vx,vy,scale=3)
    plt.xlabel(r'$x $')
    plt.ylabel(r'$y $')
    plt.gcf().savefig(path + 'v_'+name+'.png', format='png', bbox_inches='tight')    
    plt.clf()
```

What can cause this error? I am not defining the equation inside the loop (this caused a similar problem before). Thank you in advance for your help.

UPDATE
I changed the function calling for x.mesh as
`delta_func(xp,yp,sigma)` where xp and yp are `xp=Variable(value=mesh.x-Rx)` and `yp=Variable(value=mesh.y-Ry)`. Directly calling the x.mesh might have caused the problem according to an answer to my [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67630817/how-to-avoid-stack-overflow-error-in-fipy-pde-solver). But that did not help, I am still getting the overflow error. Here is the new version of the code:

```
"""

"""

from fipy import (CellVariable, PeriodicGrid2D, Viewer, TransientTerm, DiffusionTerm,
                  UniformNoiseVariable, LinearLUSolver, numerix,
                  ImplicitSourceTerm, ExponentialConvectionTerm, VanLeerConvectionTerm,
                  PowerLawConvectionTerm, Variable)

import sys
import inspect

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage

from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.signal import correlate
from scipy.stats import kurtosis
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

numerix.random.seed(2)

def run_simulation(f0, Total_time):

    # Define mesh size and number of points
    nx = 50
    ny = nx
    L = 50
    dx = L / nx
    dy = dx
    
    mesh = PeriodicGrid2D(dx, dy, nx, ny)
    
    # Variables to use
    vx = CellVariable(name='vx', mesh=mesh, hasOld=1)
    vy = CellVariable(name='vy', mesh=mesh, hasOld=1)
    m = CellVariable(name='m', mesh=mesh, hasOld=1)
    
    # Initial condition
    m.setValue(UniformNoiseVariable(mesh=mesh, minimum=0.6215, maximum=0.6225))
    vx.setValue(UniformNoiseVariable(mesh=mesh, minimum=0, maximum=0.00001))
    vy.setValue(UniformNoiseVariable(mesh=mesh, minimum=0, maximum=0.00001))

    #particle position
    x0=10.0
    y0=25.0
    # create grids for grad function
    xgrid=np.unique(mesh.x.value)+dx/2
    ygrid=np.unique(mesh.y.value)+dy/2

    # parameters ------------------------------
    B=4.0
    Gamma=1.0
    gamma=1.0
    Dm=0.005
    C=100.0
    ## save the initial positions in Rx,Ry
    Rx=Variable(value=x0)
    Ry=Variable(value=y0)
    theta=Variable(value=0.0)               # n-hat = cos(theta) x-hat + sin(theta) y-hat
    sigma = 1
    dt = 0.05
    #-----------------------------------------
    xp=Variable(value=mesh.x-Rx)
    yp=Variable(value=mesh.y-Ry)

    x_hat = [1.0, 0.0]
    y_hat = [0.0, 1.0]

    #------------- dirac delta function -------------- 
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58041222/dirac-delta-source-term-in-fipy

    def delta_func(x, y, epsilon):
        return ((x < epsilon) & (x > -epsilon) & (y < epsilon) & (y > -epsilon)) * \
        (1 + numerix.cos(numerix.pi * x / epsilon) * numerix.cos(numerix.pi * y / epsilon)) / 2 / epsilon



    ############## equations #############
    # renormalized parameters by Gamma
    
    # fields : velocity vector, density scalar
    #       Gamma * v = -B rho(grad(rho)) + f* n-cap* delta(r-R),     B>0, f>0, Gamma>0
    #       dot(rho) + del.(v rho) = 0
    # particle
    #       dot(R) = (f/gamma)*(n-cap) - (C/gamma) * rho(grad(rho))      C>0

    # Gamma=gamma=1,  B' = B/Gamma, C'=C/gamma, f'=f/Gamma

    ######################################

    eq_m = (TransientTerm(var=m) + ExponentialConvectionTerm(coeff=x_hat * vx + y_hat * vy, var=m) ==  DiffusionTerm(coeff=Dm, var=m) )

    eq_vx = (ImplicitSourceTerm(coeff=1., var=vx) == -(B/Gamma)*m.grad.dot(x_hat)*(m) + (f0/Gamma)*numerix.cos(theta)* delta_func(xp,yp,sigma) )

    eq_vy = (ImplicitSourceTerm(coeff=1., var=vy) == -(B/Gamma)*m.grad.dot(y_hat)*(m) + (f0/Gamma)*numerix.sin(theta)* delta_func(xp,yp,sigma) )

    eq = eq_m & eq_vx & eq_vy

    viewer = Viewer(vars=(m))
    
    elapsed = 0.0
    
    ms = []
    vxs = []
    vys = []
    xs = []
    ys = []
    
    while elapsed < Total_time:
        # Old values are used for sweeping when solving nonlinear values
        vx.updateOld()
        vy.updateOld()
        m.updateOld()

        print(elapsed, Rx, Ry)      

        mgrid=np.reshape(m.value,(nx,ny))
        # gradient cal, dydx[0][x,y], dydx[1][x,y] -> x derivative, y derivative at x,y
        dydx=np.gradient(mgrid,dx,dy,edge_order=2)
        # impose periodic boundary on gradient
        dydx[0][nx-1,:]=(mgrid[0,:]-mgrid[nx-2,:])/(2.0*dx)
        dydx[0][0,:]=(mgrid[1,:]-mgrid[nx-1,:])/(2.0*dx)
        dydx[1][:,ny-1]=(mgrid[:,0]-mgrid[:,ny-2])/(2.0*dy)
        dydx[1][:,0]=(mgrid[:,1]-mgrid[:,ny-1])/(2.0*dy)
        

        # solve ode
        idx = np.argmin(np.abs(xgrid - Rx))
        idy = np.argmin(np.abs(ygrid - Ry))

        x0=x0+ ((f0/gamma)*np.cos(theta) - C*mgrid[idx,idy]*dydx[0][idx,idy])*dt
        y0=y0+ ((f0/gamma)*np.sin(theta) - C*mgrid[idx,idy]*dydx[1][idx,idy])*dt

        if(x0>L):
          x0=x0-L
        if(x0<0):
          x0=x0+L

        if(y0>L):
          y0=y0-L
        if(y0<0):
          y0=y0+L

           
        Rx.setValue(x0) # element-wise assignment did not work 
        Ry.setValue(y0)

        elapsed += dt
        
        res = 1e5
        old_res = res * 2
        step = 0
        while res > 1e-5 and step < 5 and old_res / res > 1.01:            
            old_res = res
            res = eq.sweep(dt=dt)
            step += 1


        # The variable values are just numpy arrays so easy to use!
        # save velocity & density
        vxs.append(vx.value.copy())
        vys.append(vy.value.copy())
        ms.append(m.value.copy())


        viewer.plot()
    # save x and y positions
    xs.append(mesh.x.value.copy())
    ys.append(mesh.y.value.copy())
        
    return ms, vxs, vys, xs, ys

if __name__ == '__main__':

    path = 'result/'

    Total_time= 100 #40
    
    f0 = 2
    ms, vxs, vys, xs, ys = run_simulation(f0,Total_time)

    name = 'f0_{:.4f}'.format(f0)
        
    y = np.array([ms, vxs, vys])
    xx = np.reshape(xs,(50,50))
    yy = np.reshape(ys,(50,50))
    vx = np.reshape(vxs[380][:],(50,50))
    vy = np.reshape(vys[380][:],(50,50))
    print(np.shape(xx), np.shape(xs), np.shape(vx))
    #np.save(path + name, y)

    plt.imshow(np.reshape(ms[380][:],(50,50)), aspect='auto', interpolation='bicubic', cmap='jet', extent=[0, 50, 50, 0])
    plt.colorbar(label='density m')
    plt.xlabel(r'$x $')
    plt.ylabel(r'$y $')
    plt.gcf().savefig(path + 'rho_'+name+'.png', format='png', bbox_inches='tight')    
    plt.clf()

#---------------------------------------------
    plt.imshow(np.reshape(vxs[380][:],(50,50)), aspect='auto', interpolation='bicubic', cmap='jet', extent=[0, 50, 50, 0])
    plt.colorbar(label='velocity vx')
    plt.xlabel(r'$x $')
    plt.ylabel(r'$y $')
    plt.gcf().savefig(path + 'vel_'+name+'.png', format='png', bbox_inches='tight')    
    plt.clf()

#---------------------------------------------
    plt.quiver(xx,yy,vx,vy,scale=3)
    plt.xlabel(r'$x $')
    plt.ylabel(r'$y $')
    plt.gcf().savefig(path + 'v_'+name+'.png', format='png', bbox_inches='tight')    
    plt.clf()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must confess that I ran out of patience before getting the stack overflow error, but I was able to identify the problem.
It's a similar (although more subtle) issue to what you [reported before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67630817/2019542). Because `theta` is declared as a `Variable`,

```py
x0=x0+ ((f0/gamma)*np.cos(theta) - C*mgrid[idx,idy]*dydx[0][idx,idy])*dt
y0=y0+ ((f0/gamma)*np.sin(theta) - C*mgrid[idx,idy]*dydx[1][idx,idy])*dt
```

result in longer and longer `Variable` expressions (and longer and longer step times). I.e., `x0 = (((x0_0 + dx0_1) + dx0_2) + dx0_3) + dx0_4 + ...`

Changing these to

```py
x0=x0+ (((f0/gamma)*np.cos(theta) - C*mgrid[idx,idy]*dydx[0][idx,idy])*dt).value
y0=y0+ (((f0/gamma)*np.sin(theta) - C*mgrid[idx,idy]*dydx[1][idx,idy])*dt).value
```

resolves this issue.

### Addressing the warning following the question edit

The warning in the comments about "...has been cast to a constant `CellVariable`" is due to:

```py
xp=Variable(value=mesh.x-Rx)
yp=Variable(value=mesh.y-Ry)
```

This is definitely not recommended. This takes the `MeshVariable` objects `mesh.x` and `mesh.y` and then throws away the mesh. When the result is later associated with a mesh, e.g., by multiplying by another `MeshVariable` or using as a `SourceTerm`, FiPy warns because it looks like it could fit on the mesh, but it's not on a mesh. Just use

```py
xp=mesh.x-Rx
yp=mesh.y-Ry
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I did not realize the x,y position update equation will change the Variable expression. Can you explain a little bit what is changing by adding the `.value` ? Is it like the Variable expression is not being changed after adding the `.value` ?

Comment: To add to the previous comment: I have checked for long run and the code is running fine! Thanks again. However it is showing some warning like this UserWarning: The expression `((cos(Variable(value=array(0.))) * 2.0) * (((((((Variable(value=array([-9.5, -8.5, -7.5, ..., 37.5, 38.5, 39.5])) < 1) & (Variable(value=array([-9.5, -8.5, -7.5, ..., 37.5, 38.5, 39.5])) > -1)) & ...the whole delta function return` has been cast to a constant `CellVariable` is this because how the delta function is defined?

Comment: The code you posted generates this warning, or have you changed it? The warning occurs because you are trying to calculate something that has the shape of a `CellVariable`, but it's not a `CellVariable`. The expression you've posted comes from the last term in `eq_vx`.

Comment: For me, it says things like `((CellVariable(value=array([[ 0.5,  1.5,  2.5, ..., 47.5, 48.5, 49.5],
       [ 0.5,  0.5,  0.5, ..., 49.5, 49.5, 49.5]]), mesh=PeriodicGrid2D(dx=1.0, nx=50, dy=1.0, ny=50))[index] - Variable(value=array(10.))) < 1)`, rather than `((Variable(value=array([-9.5, -8.5, -7.5, ..., 37.5, 38.5, 39.5])) < 1)`.

Comment: Are you passing different arguments to `delta_func()` than in your codes sample above?

Comment: Also, what version of FiPy are you using? What platform? What version of Python? What version of numpy?

Comment: In answer to your other question, [`.value`](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/fipy/generated/fipy.variables.html#fipy.variables.variable.Variable.value) is the instantaneous value of a `Variable()` (`Variable.value` is just a numpy array; it doesn't support lazy evaluation).

Comment: To clarify, your code does not generate a warning about `has been cast to a constant CellVariable` for me.

Comment: My second example code is wrong. That was giving the warning. My first example code (before EDIT) with your correction does not give the warning as you said. I changed the arguments in the `delta_func()` after the EDIT and that is why I think I was getting the warning. Thanks for the explanation, makes sense.

Comment: I use Ubuntu, anaconda 3, Python 3.7.6, (probably) fipy 3.4.3 or older.

Comment: OK, I've revised my answer to address the warning. In future, please ask new questions about new issues. StackOverflow is really not suited to iterative troubleshooting.

Comment: Point taken, thanks again! Sorry for asking about the related issue in the comments. Will keep in mind! Love stackoverflow!